# Laravel Telescope trying to load assets prefixed with ASSET_URL value

Tags: laravel, laravel-10, laravel-telescope

I installed Telescope but when I go to `/telescope` the page is all messed up. Checking the Chrome console, I see a bunch of errors like this:

```
GET https://asdfasdfasdf.cloudfront.net/vendor/telescope/app.css?id=hjlasjlasdfjllasfjkl net::ERR_ABORTED 403
```

All other assets on the site are served thru CloudFront by prefixing with the `ASSET_URL` value during the Vite build.

This has never been a problem with anything else, but for some reason Telescope is trying to reference the contents of the `public/vendor/telescope` assets dir with the CloudFront distribution prefix.

I tried adding them to the Vite build, but that didn't help because Telescope appears to use Mix still.

If I comment out `ASSET_URL` in the `.env` then I get this error when I try to load Telescope:

```
local.ERROR: Exception: Mix manifest not found at: /Users/myself/site/public/vendor/telescope/mix-manifest.json
```

I already ran `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=telescope-assets --force` and I can clearly see the `mix-manifest.json` file is exactly where it is saying it isn't.

[image]

How do I get the assets to show up correctly in Telescope?